# Getting incorrect top listing from Reddit API

Tags: python, api, reddit

I've been trying to retrieve the top posts from a subreddit but the listing I get back isn't right. For example if I request:
http://www.reddit.com/r/cleveland/top.json?limit=100
I only get back 3 posts.

Edit: here is the code:

```
content = loads(decode(urlopen(Request('http://www.reddit.com/r/'
                        + subreddit + '/top.json?limit=100', 
          headers={'User-Agent': 'melonbot 1.0 (by /u/Melonus)'})).read()))
```

Comment: Umm... might also want to show your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is returning the correct results for the page you are requesting.

The default view for `https://www.reddit.com/r/*subreddit*/top/` is the past 24 hours. Currently, [/r/Cleveland/top](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cleveland/top/) is has 3 posts on this page.

[image: Reddit screenshot]

The full documentation of the Reddit api is available here: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api.

The parameter you want is: `t=all`. With the full request being:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/Cleveland/top/?sort=top&t=all`

As far as I can tell, this will bring back at most 50 results.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any idea on how I might be able to fetch the top 100 posts all-time? It only gives me the top 25

Comment: Figured it out. Just had to tack on ?sort=top&t=all&limit=100 at the end